# Choosing/Normalizing HoG parameters for object detection?

Tags: python, computer-vision, feature-extraction, scikit-image

I'm using HoG features for object detection via classification.

I'm confused about how to deal with HoG feature vectors of different lengths.

I've trained my classifier using training images that all have the same size.

Now, I'm extracting regions from my image on which to run the classifier - say, using the sliding windows approach. Some of the windows that I extract are a lot bigger than the size of images the classifier was trained on. (It was trained on the smallest possible size of the object that might be expected in test images).

The problem is, when the windows I need to classify are bigger than the training image sizes, then the HoG feature vector is also much bigger than the trained model's feature vector.

So how can I use the model's feature vector to classify the extract window?

For example, let's take the dimensions of one extracted window, which is 360x240, and call it `extractedwindow`. Then let's take one of my training images, which is only 20x30, and call it `trainingsample`.

If I take the HoG feature vectors, like this:

```
fd1, hog_image1 = hog(extractedwindow, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=True, normalise=True)

fd2, hog_image2 = hog(trainingsample, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=True, normalise=True)

print len(fd1)
print len(fd2)
```

Then this is the difference in length between the feature vectors:

```
2640
616
```

So how is this dealt with? Are extracted windows supposed to be scaled down to the size of the samples the classifier was trained on? Or should the parameters for HoG features be changed/normalized according to each extracted window? Or is there another way to do this?

I'm personally working in python, using scikit-image, but I guess the problem is independent of what platform I'm using.

Comment: This website might help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, HOG basically uses a parameter that establishes the cell size in pixels. So if the image size changes, then the number of cells is different and then the descriptor is different in size.

[The main approach](http://www.researchgate.net/post/HOG_for_images_of_different_sizes2) is to use HOG is to use windows with the same size in pixels (the same size during training and also during testing). So `extracted window` should be the same size of `trainingsample`.

In [that](http://www.researchgate.net/post/HOG_for_images_of_different_sizes2) reference, one user says:

> HOG is not scale invariant. Getting the same length feature vector for
>   each image does not guarantee the scale invariance.

So you should use the same window size...

Comment: I understand that the window must be the same size... my question is - there must be a way to handle this limitation. I guess the window containing the object must be scaled down then.

Comment: Yes, you should reescale the window. But: how do you extract that window? you should choose the size of the window, aren't you? why you do not choos the same size than during the training?

Comment: Other option is to change the cell size on each window (according to the image size) to get the same final descriptor

Comment: Yes I'm choosing the size of the window, but I am going over the image at multiple scales of the window size, because it is very possible that the object I'm interested in is present on the image in a larger size.

Comment: What's the formula that computes the final descriptor length?

Comment: The formula: `HOG descriptor length = #Blocks * #CellsPerBlock * #BinsPerCell` You can find more info here: http://www.juergenwiki.de/work/wiki/doku.php?id=public:hog_descriptor_computation_and_visualization

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54264/discussion-between-phyrox-and-user961627).